# Drawer icon requires 2 clicks to open drawer

Tags: android, navigation-drawer

I have previously used Android Studio's wizard to implement the Master-Detail pattern, and tried to convert the Detail to have a drawer instead of the "up" button.

I went in AndroidManifest.xml and removed the "parent" attribute on the Detail's activity settings, but it still didn't work.

Then I realized that in my Detail Activity's onOptionsItemSelected function, I had forgotten to delete this:

```
if (id == android.R.id.home) {
            // This ID represents the Home or Up button. In the case of this
            // activity, the Up button is shown. Use NavUtils to allow users
            // to navigate up one level in the application structure. For
            // more details, see the Navigation pattern on Android Design:
            //
            // http://developer.android.com/design/patterns/navigation.html#up-vs-back
            //
            NavUtils.navigateUpTo(this, new Intent(this, SongListActivity.class));
            return true;
```

Now it sort-of works, **but I have to click the navigation drawer icon 2 times.** This is the "navigation drawer icon" I'm referring to:

[image]

I noticed that when I click on an item in the Master list, it launches the Detail activity, and **it seems to not be in focus.** The Navigation bar is not visible at first. This is what I mean by saying "Navigation Bar":

[image]

When I click the Navigation Drawer Icon once, the Navigation bar shows up. When I click it again, *then* the drawer will open.

**How do I get it so the new activity is already in focus as soon as it's launched, so I only have to click the Navigation Drawer Icon one time?**

---

**Edit:** I noticed if I try to click *anything* in the Action Bar, it takes 2 clicks. I tried several other apps on my Android and they don't have this problem. Usually, they start out with the Navigation Bar already there. Maybe I have some code hiding the Navigation Bar, making the Action Bar not be in focus?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I just looked through my code, and realized that I had forgotten to delete `rootView.setSystemUiVisibility(View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_HIDE_NAVIGATION);` from before. It was in my `onCreateView` method of my DetailFragment class. I commented it out, and the problem was immediately fixed.